# i have written this php script but the condition in the file named "add_comment" is not showing in the browser even if it is true

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

***I have tried many a times but the message that  "Name is required" and "Comment is required is not showing in browser*** 
**index.php** 
  I am creating a comment system and this is the index file for the system i dont think that there is problem in index.php i think that the problem is in the add_comment.php file the file is given down but i am not able to find the exact error

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="fontawesome-free/css/all.min.css">
    <title>Document</title>
  <body>
  <br />
  <h2 align="center"><a href="#">Comment System using PHP and Ajax</a></h2>
  <br />
  <div class="container">
   <form method="POST" id="comment_form">
    <div class="form-group">
     <input type="text" name="comment_name" id="comment_name" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Name" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
     <textarea name="comment_content" id="comment_content" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Comment" rows="5"></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
     <input type="hidden" name="comment_id" id="comment_id" value="0" />
     <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-info" value="Submit" />
    </div>
   </form>
   <span id="comment_message"></span>
   <br />
   <div id="display_comment"></div>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

 $('#comment_form').on('submit', function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  var form_data = $(this).serialize();
  $.ajax({
   url:"add_comment.php",
   method:"POST",
   data:form_data,
   dataType:"JSON",
   success:function(data)
   {
    if(data.error != '')
    {
     $('#comment_form')[0].reset();
     $('#comment_message').html(data.error);
     $('#comment_id').val('0');
     load_comment();
    }
   }
  })
```

the below file is the add_comment.php file

```
<?php

$connect = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=testing', 'root', '');

$error = '';
$comment_name = '';
$comment_content = '';

if(empty($_POST["comment_name"]))
{
    $error .= '<p class="text-danger">Name is required</p>';
}
else
{
    $comment_name = $_POST["comment_name"];
}

if(empty($_POST["comment_content"]))
{
    $error .= '<p class="text-danger">Comment is required</p>';
}
else
{
    $comment_content = $_POST["comment_content"];
}

if($error == '')
{
    $query = "
     INSERT INTO tbl_comment 
     (parent_comment_id, comment, comment_sender_name) 
     VALUES (:parent_comment_id, :comment, :comment_sender_name)
     ";
    $statement = $connect->prepare($query);
    $statement->execute(
        array(
            ':parent_comment_id' => $_POST["comment_id"],
            ':comment'    => $comment_content,
            ':comment_sender_name' => $comment_name
            )
        );
    $error = '<label class="text-success">Comment Added</label>';
}

$data = array(
    'error'  => $error
    );

echo json_encode($data);

?>
```

Comment: When you console.log that data in success callback what you get?

Comment: I think `<script>` should be before `</html>`, I'm not sure if anything after it gets processed.

Comment: In console it shows nothing

Comment: I tried  by moving <script> in body but didn't work

Comment: I don't know how to do console.log the data I am a newbie

Comment: @Jacksparrow Inside your success function write a console.log(data) and check your dev console, see if the data is empty or not